# No EC2 instances are running but website is being served

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

So I have a website that was still being served even though I did not have an EC2 instance running on the us-east-1 dashboard.

I did have a load balancer running. When I terminated the load balancer the website is no longer being served.

My question is this...

Even though I had a load balancer there were no EC2 instances running. Where is the website being loaded from?

Doesn't an EC2 instance need to be running?

Comment: What is the website?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, first of all, check if you have an Instance running in a different AWS region. If not, your site could be running in multiple other AWS Services like ECS, EKS or could be deployed Serverless (if the website is a Single Page Application: react, angular, vue).

So to answer your question: No, you don't need an EC2 instance running on AWS to host a website. And load balancers can be deployed in front of many other services that are not running on EC2.